# Xamarin Forms Map resets back to last set region

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have one issue with the forms map.

When control is panned and the device rotated, the map's region is set to the LastMoveToRegion which is not the current region of the map.

I observed this both on iOS and Android. The expectation is that the map center / zoom level is retained.

Any solution?

Comment: You can refer to this link https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1520, PatrickCunningham55's workaround to create custom renderer that inherits Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android.MapRenderer and implements Android.Gms.Maps.IOnMapReadyCallback.

Comment: This solution does not work well. Also, it's only for Android.I need both Android and iOS(Xamarin Forms).

Comment: xamarin forms did not have specific method to achieve it. Base on my research, this issue should be achieved in different platforms with custom renderer.